# Lazysizes - detect when preloadAfterLoad starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I'm using the awesome lazysizes script in conjunction with Owl Carousel 2. They work great together.  I have set the option:

```
lazySizesConfig.loadMode = 1;
lazySizesConfig.preloadAfterLoad = true;
```

How can I detect when lazysizes begins loading the rest of the 'lazy queue', after the initial 'in-view' images have finished loading?

I know that this happens after the window onload event, so I could just listen for window onload. But when I read this:

https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

It says there are caveats when using the load event with images e.g. It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser, can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache etc.

I've used plugins in the past like [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) and [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) but is there a way to go without these?